# Database Structure for Preference selection

Tags: django, database, data-structures

I have two models, `user` and `course` who should be matched. To provide a basis for this matching, both models can rank the other one. I'm trying to figure out a database structure to efficiently store the preferences. The problem is, that the number of ranks is unknown (depending of number of users/courses).

I'm using Django with Postgres, if this helps.

I tried storing the preferences as a field with a pickled dictionary, but this causes problems if a model stored in the dict is updated and takes a long time to load.

I'm thankful for any tips or suggestions for improvement.

Comment: I suggest looking into the stable marriage problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: thanks but my problem isn't the matching algorithm but rather a way to structure my database to efficiently store the preferences.